# Measure (SOAP) API call performances

Tags: soap-api, performance

Is there a way to measure SF server processing time for specific (SOAP) API method call?

Example: I am invoking update of 200 objects in one request. I would like to see SF processing time on their server, not affected by network and client side processing. It would be the best if I could do that for specific API user or specific session ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I will use developer console  for checking the salesforce processing time .The time stamp on each line will give an idea of amount of time consumed do DML action by salesforce

Comment: Looks like valid approach. Combining with the "Debugging Apex API Calls" (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_API_calls.htm), it should be sufficient.